# Does SSRS lock the table when querying?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

my senior told me that for SQL Query execution by default doesn't lock the table.

But i was having some issues with my SSRS report which seems to be getting some issues with locking and getting some errors.

I did some googling but fall short of finding anything.

Just looking for confirmation does SSRS report actually will lock any tables that is being queried?

And are there any MSDN documentation that document this behavior down specifically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SSRS doesn't lock anything on its own. The locking will be driven by **your** queries embeded in the reports. Nobody can answer this question but you, look at the reports and the queries used and then see if they lock or not lock tables.

Normally queries do lock *data* in the tables, not tables. Consistent, correct, reports absolutely do require locking. Do not succumb to the fallacy of adding NOLOCK hint and call it a day, [you **will** get incorrect results](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2007/02/01/previously-committed-rows-might-be-missed-if-nolock-hint-is-used.aspx).

If you see contention in production caused by reporting, then there are many solutions. Offload reporting to a read-only server, using [Availability Groups](http://rusanu.com/2010/11/11/alwayson-high-availability-and-reads-scale-out/), a [database snapshot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175158.aspx) or a [standby log shipping server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187103.aspx). Another approach is to [enable row versioned isolation levels like SNAPSHOT](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/08/deadlocked.html).

Comment: cool, cause i was kind of lost, so it's actually query specific then rather then due to SRSS? As i was actually trying to run the query straight from reportserver/reports from multiple browsers.

Answer (score 0):

for straight select statement from SSRS will definitely lock the table.

You can use NOLOCK and write a specific query with required columns to be displayed in the report.

Here your select query must not have "*" insted have column names there.

Comment: hi are you able to provide the MSDN article link for this? thanks